# Selectively pull data into new column based off several other conditions in other columns but different rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Input:

```
df<-data.frame(df<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
P=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3),
G=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
NPO=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA),   
PO=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
T=c(0,1,2,NA,NA,1,2,3,5,NA,NA,NA,1,2,4,0,1))
```

I'd like to generate a new column "C" that indicates with "1" which non-"NA" cells from Column "T" have an endpoint that corresponds with the "1" in Column "G" and a starting point beginning with the "1" in Column "NPO". The

"PO" and "P" columns can maybe be used to help indicate that there is a new segment of data to examine? There will only ever be one run of "1"s in the new column "C" in any given run of values for "P" and will be at most as long as a run of values in "PO". The PO value resets every time there is a "1" in "NPO" or after a "1" in "G." "P" keeps increasing with every "1" in "G."

I've tried a few ifelse statements but don't know how to indicate rows that are different from the same row or how to do so without also referencing the column that I'm trying to create.

Output:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
P=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3),
G=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
NPO=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA),   
PO=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
T=c(0,1,2,NA,NA,1,2,3,5,NA,NA,NA,1,2,4,0,1),
C=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0))

ID P  G  NPO PO T   C
1  1  0  1   1  0   0
2  1  0  NA  1  1   0
3  1  0  NA  1  2   0
4  1  0  NA  1  NA  0
5  1  0  NA  1  NA  0
6  1  0  1   2  1   1
7  1  0  NA  2  2   1
8  1  0  NA  2  3   1
9  1  1  NA  2  5   1
10 2  0  NA  0  NA  0
11 2  0  NA  0  NA  0
12 2  0  NA  0  NA  0
13 2  0  1   1  1   1
14 2  0  NA  1  2   1
15 2  1  NA  1  4   1
16 3  0  1   1  0   0
17 3  0  0   1  1   0
```

Comment: I have added some details regarding the "segments", essentially runs of the same value within "P" and and "PO"

Comment: Much clearer now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(P, PO) %>%
  mutate(C = +(first(NPO == 1) & last(G == 1)))

# A tibble: 17 x 7
# Groups:   P, PO [5]
      ID     P     G   NPO    PO     T     C
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
 2     2     1     0    NA     1     1     0
 3     3     1     0    NA     1     2     0
 4     4     1     0    NA     1    NA     0
 5     5     1     0    NA     1    NA     0
 6     6     1     0     1     2     1     1
 7     7     1     0    NA     2     2     1
 8     8     1     0    NA     2     3     1
 9     9     1     1    NA     2     5     1
10    10     2     0    NA     0    NA     0
11    11     2     0    NA     0    NA     0
12    12     2     0    NA     0    NA     0
13    13     2     0     1     1     1     1
14    14     2     0    NA     1     2     1
15    15     2     1    NA     1     4     1
16    16     3     0     1     1     0     0
17    17     3     0    NA     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `fill` function from `tidyr`. This is entirely based on filling upward consecutive non-missing values in `T` with 1s, and putting 0s everywhere else.

I don't use the `P`, `NPO`, or `PO` columns at all. If that doesn't make sense, you may need to elaborate more.

```
df$result = ifelse(is.na(df$T), 0, NA)
df$result[df$G == 1] = 1
df = tidyr::fill(df, result, .direction = "up")
df$result[is.na(df$result)] = 0
df
all(df$C == df$result)
# [1] TRUE
```